# Add List-ID header to newsletters for easier filtering

Tags: feature-request, newsletter

Stack Exchange newsletters currently don't include a [`List-Id:` header](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2919.txt), or indeed any easy way to filter them other than `Subject:` header.

For example, you could use something like `List-Id: <history.list-id.stackexchange.com>` for the History Stack Exchange newsletter.

PS: The Message-ID on that message was `<2.ffa89d65a6400c8e9c1e@NY-WEB01>`—it looks like you've accidentally appended just the hostname, instead of a FQDN. That doesn't guarantee global uniqueness.